# Why can't I print out a dataframe in "markdown" format using knitr::kable() in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown, knitr, kable

I follow [this page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) and try to print out a dataframe in "markdown" format. It still worked like two hours ago, and all I have done during this time is writing code and installing a new package `gridExtra`. But I don't think these are relevant? How can I solve this?

[image: snapshot]

---

**Update:**

I just restart the laptop and the command works again, only now it just outputs exactly the same thing regardless of the `format` I specify.
[image: print out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your code and executed it with success. Your code is ok. The problem may be a missing complement installation or your environment. For example,  if you are using **pdf_document** in the **YAML** of your RMarkdown script, check your environment to see if you have all the required non R Tools. Depending on your operating system you will need: Miktex(Windows), Mactex(OS X) or Tex Live (Linux).

If you put all your code attached, I may help you to check all it.

Regards.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! This is quite curious. I restart my laptop and the command works again. Although now it seem to print out exactly the same thing no matter what `format` I specify... totally weird. I just upload another snapshot